# Paint the intersection area of text inside a circle

Tags: java, swing, text, graphics, intersection

I want to write a text on a circle. The intersection area of the text and circle must be a different color.

At first I thought to use area class, but I couldn't figure out how to convert a text to an area.

I still have no idea how to convert a text to a shape or something.

Here is the example picture:

[image: http://i.hizliresim.com/wOW2oQ.png]

```
void paintComponent(Graphics g){
Ellipse2D myEllipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(20,20,100,100);

//i have no idea how to create a text as a shape.
//if i was able to create a text as a shape,i would name it "myText"

a1.add(new Area(myEllipse));
a2.add(new Area(myText)); 

g2.setColor(Color.red);
g2.fill(myEllipse);

g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
g2.fill(myText);

a1.intersect(a2);
g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2.fill(a1);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6295084/261156)?

Comment: i couldn't add an image because i haven't 10 reputation. Here is the picture about what a want. http://i.hizliresim.com/wOW2oQ.png

Comment: thank @Gilbert Le Blanc for adding picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward to draw a circle and draw text.  Thanks to [king_nak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22782557/300257) for the Graphics2D method to change the color of the text in the circle.

[image: Simple Painting]

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimplePainting implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Painting");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
        frame.add(paintPanel);

        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimplePainting());
    }

    class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 
                -5950526117015270963L;

        private Ellipse2D myEllipse = 
                new Ellipse2D.Double(20, 20, 100, 100);

        private String myText = "Testing, one, two, three";

        public PaintPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setXORMode(Color.WHITE);

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fill(myEllipse);

            g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g2d.drawString(myText, 70, 70);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer but i need to change the color of text in the circle.

Comment: i did it with a lot of shapes like rectangle, ellipse, oval... but when it comes to text, i really don't know

Comment: thank you @Gilbert Le Blanc, i really appreciate for all answers. As soon as i finish my program i will share in here

Comment: @Murat: When you have a chance, accept king_nak's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The painting engine can handle this by itself. Take a look at the XOR-Mode for Graphics:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setXORMode(java.awt.Color)

In your example, you have to set the XOR color to White before writing the text:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

g2.setColor(Color.white);
g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g2.fill(myEllipse);

g2.setColor(Color.red);
g2.setXORMode(Color.white); // Set XOR mode to white
g2.drawString(myText, 70, 70);
```

It can be quite tricky to find the correct XOR color. But with regards to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127187/what-does-graphics-setxormodecolor-do-in-simple-terms), you have to bitwise XOR the foreground of the graphics, the XOR-Color, and the color you're painting onto.

For the circle area we get:

```
Foreground = FF 00 00 (red)
XOR-Color  = FF FF FF (white)
Background = 00 00 FF (blue)
----------------------
Result     = 00 FF 00 (green)
```

and outside:

```
Foreground = FF 00 00 (red)
XOR-Color  = FF FF FF (white)
Background = FF FF FF (white)
----------------------
Result     = FF 00 00 (red)
```

**Update:**

To find the XOR / Foreground pair, you can do the following:

You have to combine the background and resulting color by XOR. We see that for both cases (in ellipse and outside), we have

```
Ellispe: 00 00 FF ^ 00 FF 00 = 00 FF FF
Outside: FF FF FF ^ FF 00 00 = 00 FF FF
```

So we can choose any XOR / Foreground pair that results in `00 FF FF` by XOR. In the example, I used white and red, but black and cyan would yield the same result.